# Jquery selectors in a loop give unclear results

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am confused: whats going on with the following code

```
var ProductFeatures = [];

for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    ProductFeatures.push({
        Guid: $('#FeatureListTable tr').eq(i).attr('id'),
        Value: $('#FeatureListTable td:nth-child(5)').eq(i-1).val(),
        Remark: $('#FeatureListTable td:nth-child(6) input').eq(i-1).val()
    });
}
```

When I comment out the "Value:" row, I get a different result in the Remark field than when there are no comments

```
// Value: $('#FeatureListTable td:nth-child(5)').eq(i-1).val(),
```

Why does this happen?

Thanks in advance, Julian

Comment: Who ever reads this question in the future - Please do not use this code for your projects unless you are looking for an example of how not to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the `Remark` value would change when you comment out the `Value` line, but this line:

```
Value: $('#FeatureListTable td:nth-child(5)').eq(i-1).val(),
```

...would only return `null` or `undefined` (I don't remember which one), because it is trying to get the `value` of a `<td>` instead of a form input.

This sort of data structure is much better built using jQuery's `.map()` method.

Comment: @Patrick - I totally agree that the code is bad. I was trying to figure out how to improve it and then noticed that the results were changing between runs, I thought I better understand whats going on first. Then I could ask a more intelligent question how to fix it and make it efficient.

Comment: @Julian: Sorry, I mis-read the question, and thought you were looking at someone else's code, and needed and explanation of what it does. I'll delete the first part of my answer.

Comment: @Patrick - When the line is commented out the results in the Remark field are as expected. When the Value field is not commented out the remark actually skips and brings the result from the next row in the table

Comment: @Julian: I had to break away for a bit. If you post our HTML, I can try to give a quick example of `$.map()` using your code.

Comment: @Patrick - thanks for your time, as we live in different time zones I missed your post. I have opened a separate question regarding the map function you recommended, If you feel like take a look its  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614202/jquery-map-for-an-html-table-help-needed

Comment: @Julian: I added an answer to that other question. If there's nothing else that pertains to this question, you can go ahead and confirm it complete. If there's anything else I can answer on this one, let me know. :o)

Comment: @Patrick - Thank you again for all of your help - I have accepted the answer for the other question. As for this question I guess its not relevant any more.